# What would cause WaitForSingleObject with finite timeout not to return?

Tags: multithreading, winapi, c++builder, indy

The title says it all.  I am using C++ Builder to submit a form to an Internet server using TIdHTTP->Post(), to get a response.  Since that call can get stuck if there is a network problem or a server problem, I am trying to run it in a separate thread.  When the Post() returns, I signal the Event that I am waiting for with WaitForSingleObject, using a timeout of 1000.  At one point, I was processing messages after the timeouts, but now I am just repeating the WaitForSingleObject call with a timeout of 1000 again, until the event is signaled or my total timeout period (20 seconds) has elapsed.  If the timeout elapses, I would call Disconnect() on the TIdHTTP and try again.

However, I have not been able to get this to work reliably, although it usually works.  I am using CodeSite to log the progress, and I can see that, on occasion, WaitForSingleObject is called, but does not return (ever).  Since WaitForSingleObject is being called on the main thread, the application is then unresponsive until it is killed.

While one must always think of memory corruption when a C++ program stalls, I don't think that is what is going on.  The stall is always at the WaitForSingleObject call, and if it was a memory corruption issue, I would expect that, at least sometimes, something else would go wrong.

The MSDN page for WaitForSingleObject says that the timer does not count down while the computer is asleep, and the monitor does go blank after a while, but the computer continues to run, and in any case WaitForSingleObject does not return once the mouse is moved and the monitor comes back on.

So, again, my question.  What could be causing WaitForSingleObject with a finite timeout (1000 msecs) to never return?

Comment: It should return. Can we have an SSCCE.

Comment: Of course, that is the problem -- it is part of a much larger application which is doing lots of things.  Let me work on stripping it down to an SSCCE.

Comment: Pretty much pointless posting without SSCCE

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that you actually have something different from what you expect. For example, you provide bad arguments causing exception such as access violation, and the application freezes for another reason. Being unable to notice this, you ask a question that has no answer on its own, and is eventually not really helpful in your case.

Comment: Sorry.  I had been trying to figure this out for a couple of weeks, and was hoping that someone else had seen something like this.  I will continue working on trying to narrow it down.

Comment: When `Post()` fails, are you catching the exception so you can still signal your event? Or are you allowing the exception to skip the signaling? Personally, I would not bother with a waitable event at all. I would put a 20s `ReadTimeout` on the `TIdHTTP` itself, and let the thread terminate when `Post()` exits for any reason. Then the main thread can `WaitFor()` the thread to terminate, or use the thread's `OnTerminate` event.

Comment: You do have just *one* thread waiting on that event do you? From your description, it sounds like you do, but worth asking just in case.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  Regarding Post() fails, I am catching the exceptions and then signaling the event.  I am even catching (...), just to be sure nothing is leaking.  I do have just one thread waiting on the event.  Thanks for the suggestion, Remy - I will try it.

Comment: I haven't used C++ Builder, so I do not know what diagnostic tools it has. You could, however, compile your code with Visual Studio and instantly have memory diagnostics compiled into your application. The CRT debug facilities are fairly nice, and help you catch memory corruption when it happens (assuming this is a memory corruption bug).

Comment: I have seen odd behavior with `WaitForSingleObject()` on Windows 7. Sometimes I use `WFSO()` to wait for a `TThread` to finish terminatig, and even though `TThread` calls `ExitThread()` on itself correctly, `WFSO()` sometimes does not exit correctly, as if the thread handle is not being signaled correctly. Makes me wonder if there is an underlying bug in `WFSO()` itself that gets triggered under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer to my question is "Something Else".  In this case, I finally tracked it down to a library I was using that also used threads.  It worked with a previous version of RAD Studio, but disabling that library fixed this issue.  I am moving to the current version of that library and will re-test.

I had read about problems with WFSO causing blocks, and even where Sleep might never return if there were too many threads running ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), so I thought there might be something I didn't know about threads and WFSO causing this.

Thanks to everyone for your helpful comments which pointed me in the right direction, and especially to Remy Lebeau for his suggestions on managing Post timeouts with Indy, which he maintains.